# Python's replace() function unexpectedly removing multiple double-occurrence characters

Tags: python

I have a block of code that should remove every letter from that a string whose index is divisible by 3:

```
s = input()

len = len(s)

for i in range(0, len):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        s = s.replace(s[i], ' ')

s = s.replace(' ', '')
print(s)
```

The string "Python" for example produces "yton" as expected. I have tested this with a dozen or so strings with the correct output, *except* for one curious case:

The string "Hello" produces "eo" instead of "elo". Upon closer inspection, python is removing double-occurences, such as "ll". Why would this be?

Comment: Because `replace` always replaces every occurrence of a substring...

Comment: ...unless you pass it a third parameter which is a count of the number of times to perform the replacement.

Comment: As a side note, `len = len(s)` is a really bad idea. Once you do that, you can never call the `len` function again, because now you're trying to call the number 40 (or whatever).

Comment: @abarnert since this seems to be a pedantic comments section, you could just do `del len` :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure, or you could even do `globals()[codecs.decode('ary', 'rot13')[::-1] = lambda x: __import__('builtins').len(x)`.

Comment: Also, even if you had passed the `count` argument to `.replace`, your logic is still wrong. Why would you expect `ython`? You should expect `yton`. The problem is every time your remove an element, it *shifts* the indices. There's better ways to do this. At the very least, you should keep a reference to the full string around and use *those* indices.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was expecting `yton`, not `ython`. I deliberately didn't shift the indices and instead replaced them with spaces.

For clarification, I'm doing the snakify.org exercises, and there are limitations, based on lesson, as to what functions and language features can be used at certain stages.

Comment: @devgeist aaa yes. Didn't even see this. Good call, sir.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No worries, appreciate your input!

Comment: But even if you had passed `count`, it would still be wrong, as I explained in a comment under QA Collective's answer. For example, given the string `'Pythony'`, what do you think is going to happen when you `s = s.replace(s[6], ' ')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) does:

> Return a copy of the string with **all occurrences of substring *old* replaced by *new*.** If the optional argument *count* is given, only the first *count* occurrences are replaced.

You're actually relying on exactly that behavior in your `replace(' ', '')` call.

When you don't want that, don't use `replace`. (In fact, almost *any* use of `s.replace(s[i], …)` has exactly this problem, so watch out whenever you find yourself writing that.)

For example, you can just use slicing:

```
s = s[:i] + ' ' + s[i+1:]
```

---

Or, maybe even better, just build up a list of characters and `join` them at the end:

```
s = input()
lst = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    if i % 3:
        lst.append(s[i])
s = ''.join(lst)
```

… which you can even condense into a one-liner:

```
s = ''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(s) if i % 3)
```

---

If you're really not allowed to use `join`, you can do the same logic—just less efficient and idiomatic—with string concatenation:

```
s = input()
t = ''
for i in range(len(s)):
    if i % 3:
        t += s[i]
s = t
```

Or, just for fun, put all the complexity in the ranges and slicing so you don't even need the `%`:

```
s = input()
t = ''
for i in range(1, len(s), 3):
    t += s[i:i+2]
s = t
```

Comment: Fool am I! I even made note of this recently. I mistakenly misread my own code, thinking `s[i]` would only replace the occurrence on the index. Lesson learned!

Comment: Good call on using `join`, however I'm doing the exercises off snakify.org, which has forbidden the use (at this stage) of anything beyond `if` and `for` statements, as well as basic string and arithmetic functions.

Comment: @devgeist But if you're allowed to use the `replace` method on strings, how could you not be allowed to use the `join` method on strings? I can understand not being allowed to write generator expressions or use `enumerate`, I guess, but the explicit statement version shouldn't be doing anything forbidden.

Comment: The exercises are based on what is taught in the lessons, and `join` hasn't yet been introduced. I agree it might as well have been mentioned, as I don't think it's really "cheating" to use it.

Comment: @devgeist I think the world would be a better place if Python tutorials/classes/etc. didn't teach `str.replace` so early, because _everyone_ makes exactly the same mistake you did, and then struggles to find workarounds that seem to work but don't (like the one in QA Collective's answer), and only _then_ learns the right way to do it. It's more of an attractive nuisance than a useful feature in the early days.

Comment: love that last slice-based approach, I was trying to come up with a succinct answer demonstrating those steps but yours is better than mine by far.

Comment: Agreed - thanks @abarnert for taking the time to write that. It's very instructive. Also teaches me to read my own notes more carefully and with greater regularity!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `replace` method replaces every occurrence of the string with the replacement string. When you replace `l`, the third character of `Hello`, it also replaces the other `l` with `''`.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `s.replace` you are invoking replace on the entire string `s`, which replaces all occurrences of `s[i]`, unless you pass a third parameter to `replace()` to limit the number of times the replacement happens.

Try this in stead:

```
s = input()

len = len(s)

for i in range(0, len):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        s = s.replace(s[i], ' ', 1)

s = s.replace(' ', '')
print(s)
```

I think you could also just skip using replace and more precisely change that one character, changing the code under your `if` to:

```
t = list(s)
t[i] = ' '
s = "".join(t)
```

Comment: No, this is still wrong. What if letter 6 is a `j`, and letter 2 is also a `j`? When you do `s.replace(s[6], ' ', 1)`, what happens?

Comment: In fact, you'll even run into this with the example string `Hello`, but it isn't exactly visible there (it doesn't matter that you remove the wrong `l` after the second `replace`, since they're next to each other); try `Pythony` instead, and the problem is clearer: you get `tony` instead of `yton`.

Comment: You're right - I too read your code incorrectly as you did.  The honest truth is that if I were trying to do what you are doing, I wouldn't use replace at all.  I'd step through each of the characters and either modify the existing string or construct a new one.

Comment: Yes, that's my point: you _can't_ use `replace` for this problem. Adding `count=1` doesn't help; any solution with `replace` is wrong. (Unless you do something incredibly silly, like scan for characters that don't exist in `s` and `replace` every single character with a unique unused one so you can `replace` them back later.)